# ASP.NET controls type change after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, postback, autopostback

i need to change a DropDownList(ddlGouvPick) to TextBox(txtGouvPick) when user select a specific value from another DropDownList(ddlTypeDemande).
there is some portion of code describing my case :

ASPX Page
The DropDownList that invoke the action

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="ddlTypeDemande" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="DDDropDown" 
   AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTypeDemande_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

the TextBox will be placed here :

```
<td id="tdGouvLiv" 
runat="server" >
<asp:DropDownList 
ID="ddlGouv_Liv" 
runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGouv_Liv_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

CodeBehind :

```
    protected void ddlTypeDemande_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    switch (ddlTypeDemande.SelectedValue)
      {
        case "I": 

          TextBox vartxtGouv_Liv = new TextBox();
          tdGouvLiv.Controls.Remove(ddlGouv_Colct);
          vartxtGouv_Liv.ID = "txtGouv_Liv";
          vartxtGouv_Liv.CssClass = "DDTextBox";
          vartxtGouv_Liv.Width = 200;
          tdGouvLiv.Controls.Add(vartxtGouv_Liv);
          break;

    case "O": 

         Export(); /*Change the type of another control*/
         break;
     }
  }
```

the problem is that when i invoke a postback from another control in the page. i lose the changes.

Comment: because u danymically add this control, you have to add it again in the page oninit event

Comment: why don't you just put 2 controls and set one is hidden,  the viewstate will keep that visible/hidden value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be adding textbox and dropdownlist controls to the form and using their `Visible` property as follows:

```
switch (ddlTypeDemande.SelectedValue)
  {
    case "I": 

      vartxtGouv_Liv = true;
      ddlGouv_Colct.Visible = false;
      break;

case "O": 
      vartxtGouv_Liv = false;
      ddlGouv_Colct.Visible = true;

     Export(); /*Change the type of another control*/
     break;
 }
```